# Regex with letter number and dash without leading and trailing dash

Tags: python, regex

Sorry if my question can be simple but, I'm blocked.

I was looking for a way to validate a regex that match several cases :

- Minimum 1 character (can be letter or number)
- Maximum 100 characters (can be letter, number and dash)
- Can't start with a dash
- Can't end with a dash
- Can't have 2 following dashes

I've tried this : `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}(?:([a-zA-Z0-9][-]{0,1}){0,98}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`

It works for almost every cases. Except those 2 cases :

- `0-1234` (dash on the second character)
- If I write 100 characters (0123456789[...]blablabla) then I insert dashes inside, it still validates the string even if I don't want to go over 100 characters

Can someone help me please ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please always add your programming language / tool as the regex engines somewhat differ.

Comment: Sorry for this, I forgot. I'm developing in Python and I'm using "re" module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for lookaheads and another character class:

```
^(?!-)(?!.*-$)(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,100}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/N9qZHd/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much, seems to work. I still need to decrypt how it works but it does !

Answer (score 1):

Here's just an alternative to Jan's already perfect solution.

```
^(?:[^\W_]|(?<=[^\W_])-(?=[^\W_])){1,100}$
```

It can be "decrypted" as: between 1 and 100 occurrences of either

- a letter or digit, or
- a dash preceded and followed by a letter or digit.